# TSQL Keep valid duplicates and remove invalid duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, duplicates

I've been bashing my head against this for a while now and am getting nowhere fast; the data has to remain at line level.

I want to keep the data that arrives with the earliest, duplicates are valid.  Load1 represents a batchID. Not all values have duplicates

What I want to return

```
Code1   Code2   Code3   Load1   LoadTime
a1      a1      a1      1       2013-09-10
a1      a1      a1      1       2013-09-10
a1      a1      a1      1       2013-09-10
a2      a1      a1      2       2013-09-12
a1      a2      a1      3       2013-09-13
a1      a2      a1      3       2013-09-13
```

Any suggestions?

```
 CREATE TABLE #Test (
 Code1  varchar(10),
 Code2  varchar(10),
 Code3  varchar(10),
 Load1  varchar(10),
 LoadTime DATE
 )


  INSERT INTO #Test
  VALUES ('a1','a1','a1','1','2013-09-10') --Keep

  INSERT INTO #Test
  VALUES ('a1','a1','a1','1','2013-09-10') --Keep

  INSERT INTO #Test
  VALUES ('a1','a1','a1','1','2013-09-10') --Keep

  INSERT INTO #Test
  VALUES ('a1','a1','a1','2','2013-09-11') --Delete

  INSERT INTO #Test
  VALUES ('a2','a1','a1','2','2013-09-12') --Keep

  INSERT INTO #Test
  VALUES ('a2','a1','a1','3','2013-09-13') --Delete

  INSERT INTO #Test
  VALUES ('a1','a2','a1','3','2013-09-13') --Keep

  INSERT INTO #Test
  VALUES ('a1','a2','a1','3','2013-09-13') --Keep

  INSERT INTO #Test
  VALUES ('a1','a2','a1','4','2013-09-13')-- Delete

  INSERT INTO #Test
  VALUES ('a1','a2','a1','4','2013-09-13')-- Delete
```

Comment: What is an invalid duplicate?

Comment: I've realised that I've asked the question very badly. I'm going to have to rewrite it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use SQL Server [common table expression or CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
with cte as (
    select
        dense_rank() over(partition by Code1, Code2, Code3 order by LoadTime, Load1 asc) as rn
    from Table1
)
delete from cte where rn > 1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ee6f/3)</kbd>**

Actually this query is very easy in SQL Server, because SQL Server treats simple common table expressions as updatable views - you don't have to join cte on your original table, you can just `delete from cte`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at `row_number()` or `dense_rank()`

It's hard to tell the logic for deleting or keeping from your sample data, but something like

```
;with cte as (
      select *, 
      dense_rank() over (partition by code1,code2,code3 order by loadtime) rn 
      from #test)
    delete #Test
    from #Test t
        inner join cte
            on t.Code1 = cte.Code1
            and t.Code2 = cte.Code2
            and t.Code3 = cte.Code3
            and t.Load1 = cte.Load1
            and t.LoadTime = cte.LoadTime
        where rn>1
```

(The join is much easier if your data has a unique ID)